# How to use libgit2sharp from fsharp

Tags: f#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

this is on  `Server 2016` with `net471` which should behave like `windows 10`.

So i am dowloading via `nuget LibGit2Sharp prerelease` in my `paket.dependencies`, which resolves to

```
LibGit2Sharp (0.26.0-preview-0027)
LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries (1.0.226) - restriction: >= netstandard2.0
```

in a fresh fsi (using `ionide` ) i can reference `LibGit2Sharp.dll` and open the `LibGit2Sharp` namespace, but instantiating a Repository throws following error:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.1.0 for F# 4.1

> #r "../../packages/play/LibGit2Sharp/lib/netstandard2.0/LibGit2Sharp.dll";;

--> Referenced 'd:\scripts2dev\libwba\src\play\../../packages/play/LibGit2Sharp/lib/netstandard2.0/LibGit2Sharp.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)

> open LibGit2Sharp;;
> let  repo = new Repository("path\to\repo.git");;
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'git2-b0d9952': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.InitializeNativeLibrary()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_repository_open(git_repository*& repository, FilePath path)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options, RepositoryRequiredParameter requiredParameter)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@() in d:\scripts2dev\libwba\src\play\LibGit2Sharp.fsx:line 4
Stopped due to error
```

And I can't reference the `dll` from `LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries`, because it throws

```
> #r @"../..\packages\play\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries\runtimes\win-x64\native\git2-b0d9952.dll";;

LibGit2Sharp.fsx(7,1): error FS0229: Error opening binary file 'd:\scripts2dev\libwba\src\play\../..\packages\play\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries\runtimes\win-x64\native\git2-b0d9952.dll': d:\scripts2dev\libwba\packages\play\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries\runtimes\win-x64\native\git2-b0d9952.dll: bad cli header, rva 0

LibGit2Sharp.fsx(7,1): error FS3160: Problem reading assembly 'd:\scripts2dev\libwba\src\play\../..\packages\play\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries\runtimes\win-x64\native\git2-b0d9952.dll': Processing of a script fragment has stopped because an exception has been raised
```

What am I missing? How can I use the compiled libraries ?

Comment: I suspect this might be better as a bug report to the libgit2sharp project; for example, https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1585 from 3 days ago has very similar symptoms, though on Ubuntu Linux rather than Windows.

Comment: thanks, i created this issue https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1588 . I asked here first, because i was not sure if my attempt to use the library was correct. I find it really hard in .NET land to find proper instructions. Very often knowledge is presumed.

Comment: Github issue was created https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1588

Answer (score 0):

If you load the native dll via LoadLibrary of  kernel32 it should work. Does this help?

see also https://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/loading-native-dlls-in-fsharp-interactive.html

```
[<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```